# Shiny: Disable various inputs with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

Without additional packages like `Shinyjs`, I would like to use Javascript (preferred vanilla JS) to reactively disable various inputs in my Shiny app. However, with the exception of `checkboxInput()`, no input can be disabled. Does anyone have an explanation for this?

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  
  tags$script(
    HTML("
    $(document).on('shiny:connected', function(event) {
    
    $(document).on('shiny:inputchanged', function(event) {
    if(event.name === 'control' && event.value === 'disable'){
    
    
    document.getElementById('radio').disabled = true;
    
    document.getElementById('checkSingle').disabled = true;
    
    document.getElementById('checkGroup').disabled = true;
    
    document.getElementById('choose').disabled = true;
    
  }else{
    
    document.getElementById('radio').disabled = false;
    
    document.getElementById('checkSingle').disabled = false;
    
    document.getElementById('checkGroup').disabled = false;
    
    document.getElementById('choose').disabled = false;
   
   
  }
  });

});")),
  
  
  div(radioButtons(inputId = "control", label = "DISABLE INPUTS", choices = c("enable", "disable"))),
  div(style = "margin: 1.5rem 0; border-bottom: solid black .1rem; width: 15%;"),
  
  div(
    radioButtons(inputId = "radio", label = "RADIOBUTTON", choices = c("one", "two", "three"))),
  
  div(
    checkboxInput(inputId = "checkSingle", label = "CHECKBOX SINGLE")),
  
  div(
    checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "checkGroup", label = "CHECKBOX GROUP", choices = c("one", "two", "three"))),
  
  div(
    selectInput(inputId = "choose", label = "SELECTINPUT", choices = c("one", "two", "three"))))

server = function(input, output, session){
}
```

Comment: JQuery is included in shiny. Can you use that, or you need it truly vanilla?

Comment: can also be in JQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work:

```r
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
    tags$script(HTML(
    "
    $(document).on('shiny:connected', function(event) {
        var els = $('.my-controls');
        var toadd = els.find('input, button, textarea, a[download]');
        els = $(els.toArray().concat(toadd.toArray()));
        var selects = els.find('select').selectize();
        $(document).on('shiny:inputchanged', function(event) {
            var disabled;
            if(event.name === 'control' && event.value === 'disable'){
                disabled = true;
                els.addClass('disabled');
                selects.map(function(n) {selects[n].selectize.disable()});
            }else{
                disabled = false;
                els.removeClass('disabled');
                selects.map(function(n) {selects[n].selectize.enable()});
            }
            els.attr('disabled', disabled);
            els.prop('disabled', disabled);
        });
    });
    "
    )),
    div(radioButtons(inputId = "control", label = "DISABLE INPUTS", choices = c("enable", "disable"))),
    div(style = "margin: 1.5rem 0; border-bottom: solid black .1rem; width: 15%;"),
    div(
        class ="my-controls",
        div(radioButtons(inputId = "radio", label = "RADIOBUTTON", choices = c("one", "two", "three"))),
        div(checkboxInput(inputId = "checkSingle", label = "CHECKBOX SINGLE")),
        div(checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "checkGroup", label = "CHECKBOX GROUP", choices = c("one", "two", "three"))),
        div(selectInput(inputId = "choose1", label = "SELECTINPUT", choices = c("one", "two", "three")))
    )
)
server = function(input, output, session){}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Add all your inputs inside `div` with `my-controls` class. JS will automatically find them all.

Code modified from [shinyjs](https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs/blob/894346569df4e8198119e9608426d7d60e166aae/inst/srcjs/shinyjs-default-funcs.js#L204).

If you are sure these four types are all input types you will use, here is your answer. If not, Shinyjs did a very nice job with many special cases. I don't understand why you don't want to use it. My code doesn't cover all the special cases. Impossible for me in this post to list all cases. Please refer to shinyjs code to see how many other cases they have covered.